# $a+b\phi$ and $a+b-b\phi$ are associates in $\mathbb{Z}+\phi \mathbb{Z}$, with $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2+ab-b^2=a+b$. Show that $a+b\phi$ and $a+b-b\phi$ are associates in $\mathbb{Z}+\phi \mathbb{Z}$,  with $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

I have to find an unit $u$ such that $a+b\phi = u(a+b-b\phi)$. I've no idea how to begin, any hints? (I know that they both have the same norm, but that's just a necessary condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, you should just do the computation:

$$ \frac{a + b - b\phi}{a + b\phi} = \frac{(a + b - b\phi)(a + b - b\phi)}{a^2 + ab - b^2} = \frac{(a+b)^2 - 2(a+b)b \phi + b^2 (1 + \phi)}{a + b} $$

$$= a+b - 2b\phi + \frac{b^2}{a+b} (1 + \phi) = (2a+b-1) + (a-2b-1)\phi$$

You have already checked that these elements have the same norm (for example, because they are conjugates), so the norm of their ratio is $ 1 $, and it lies in $ \mathbf Z[\phi] $ by our computation. Hence, it is a unit in $ \mathbf Z[\phi] $, and the two elements are associates.

Comment: is it possible that you forgot the factor $\frac{b^2}{a+b}$ (going from you third fraction in the equation to your fourth)?

Comment: @Student No, I used the fact that $ (a-1)(a+b) = b^2 $.

Comment: I know, but you go from $b^2(1 + \phi)$ to $b^2\phi$? (third equation, my wording in my previous comment was not accurate)

Comment: @Student Ah, yes, you're right; but it doesn't change anything in the argument. Let me fix it.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure my computations were correct ;)